# Workable PoC of clang stack instrumentation with arm64 MTE

Tags: clang, arm64

Is there any workable PoC of clang stack instrumentation with arm64 MTE?
I tried enable clang stack instrumentation with arm64 MTE but faced with bug presented in clang which causes false positive MTE reports. I reported issue in LLVM bugzilla - https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51362.
Just interesting, does someone successfully run clang stack instrumentation with arm64 MTE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whole stack should be inited with some default allocation tag:

```
char *sp = alloc_kernel_stack();
/* set the logical tag */
sp = insert_random_tag(sp);
for (i = 0; i < STACK_SIZE; i += 16) {
/* set the allocation tag */
    set_tag(sp);
    sp += i;
}
```

This will fix MTE false positive reports. More details can be found here - https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51362